# How to: Safeguard memory - strncat()?

Tags: c, windows, string, coding-style

```
function(char *a, char *b)
{

   char newStr[100];

   strncpy(newStr, a, sizeof(newStr)); //Line 1 - copy no more than 100 bytes  

   strncat(newStr, b, (sizeof(newStr) -  strlen(newStr)));   //Line 2 - ?

   newStr[99] = NULL; //Line 3 - null terminate string

}
```

Line 2: Correct to specify 100 **bytes** minus **strlen** of what a copied over from a to ensure I don't copy over the 100 bytes?

Thank You.

Comment: This must be one of the most annoying grievances with C - the fact that `strncpy` does *not* return the number of bytes written or a pointer to the end, but rather a pointer to the beginning (which we already know, since it's one of the arguments)...

Comment: Even if you needed to null-terminate the string yourself, `NULL` is the wrong thing to use.  That's a null *pointer* constant.  A null character is `'\0'` (or just `0`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: `strncpy` is a relic from a bygone era -- it was never intended to be used as a replacement for `strcpy`.  Use `strlcpy` instead, although it's not available everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost correct. First, the NUL-termination line:

```
newStr[99] = NULL;
```

is wrong.

`strncat` always NUL-teriminates, and the third parameter is the maximum number of bytes to write *NOT* including the NUL.

Hypothetically, if `strncat` didn't NUL-terminate, the problem with that line is that it would always write to the last element of the array, even though the actual string could be much shorter.  If a and b were "Hello, " and "world!", the final array would be:

H|e|l|l|o|,| |w|o|r|l|d|!|g|i|b|b|e|r|i|s|h

where `gibberish` represents the previous contents of the array at those positions.  Only at 99, after most of these uninitialized remnants, would there be a NUL.

EDIT: Also, Keith is correct about `strncpy`.  His function is partly right, but that the second function can overflow the buffer, since it doesn't take into account the string that's already there.  The two lines combined can write 199 characters (including NUL).

Also, I was wrong about the third parameter including the NUL.  That leaves us with (modified from Keith's):

```
void function(char *a, char *b)
{
    char newStr[100];

    /* Make newStr an empty string so you can catenate onto it */
    newStr[0] = '\0';
    strncat(newStr, a, sizeof newStr - 1);
    strncat(newStr, b, sizeof newStr - strlen(newStr) - 1);

    /* Presumably you do something with newStr here */
}
```

Comment: ok, i see what you are saying about why strncat() needs to null terminate automatically. Using bytes and strlen to get the correct number of bytes in strncat() seemed odd, but on this system they are the same thing.

Comment: @Tommy, see my update.  There are some important corrections.

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy()` doesn't do what you probably think it does.

`strncat()` is a "safer" version of `strcat()` that lets you specify the size of the source array.

`strncpy()` is *not* the corresponding "safer" version of `strcpy()`.  If the target array is too big, `strncpy()` will pad it with null characters; 99% of the time this is unnecessary, since you only need a single `'\0'` to mark the end of a string.  Worse, if the target array is too small, `strncpy()` will copy as many characters as it can *and leave the target unterminated*.

`strncpy()` was designed for an obscure data structure used by early Unix systems to store file names.  A file name was stored in a fixed-length 14-byte buffer padded with null bytes.  If the file name was exactly 14 characters long, there would be no null terminator.  *This is not a string*.

In the unlikely event that that's the kind of data structure you want, then `strncpy()` is just the thing.  Otherwise, don't use it; just use `strcpy()` after confirming that the target is big enough.

Here's how I might write this function:

```
void function(char *a, char *b)
{
    char newStr[100];

    /* Make newStr an empty string so you can concatenate onto it */
    newStr[0] = '\0';
    strncat(newStr, a, sizeof newStr - 1);                  /* edited */
    strncat(newStr, b, sizeof newStr - strlen(newStr) - 1); /* edited */

    /* Presumably you do something with newStr here */
}
```

Notes:

1. Declare the return type for the function.  If you don't explicitly declare it, your compiler will probably default to `int`, but that's poor style and an obsolete language feature.
2. Avoid `strncat()`.
3. I've used `'\0'`, not `NULL`, to null-terminate the string.  `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; don't use it to denote a null *character*.

There is a substantial inefficiency here: the second `strncat()` has to re-scan from the beginning of `newStr`.  For a small number of short strings, it's not a big deal, but for large numbers of strings being catenated into a large target array, it can cause serious slowdowns.  There are ways around this, but they're either non-standard (`strlcpy()`, `strlcat()`) or inconvenient.

**EDIT**: Thanks to Matthew for pointing out errors in my code.  I *think* I've fixed them; I'm sure I can count on someone to hit me over the head if I've replaced old errors by new ones.

An alternative is:

```
snprintf(newStr, sizeof newStr, "%s%s", a, b);
```

Comment: Your second strncat call is wrong, since it will write 100 bytes *after* the existing string.

Comment: And the first is off by one (I made the same mistake in my original answer).

Comment: +1 for `snprintf` because you can specify "%s%s%s%s" and not have to worry about the hidden O(n*m) in repeated `strcat()`s

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: Fixed, I think; please check.  (I had `sizeof newStr - strlen(newStr) - 2` in the second `strncat`, but I think `sizeof newStr - strlen(newStr) - 1` is correct.)

Comment: @Dave: Yes, but it doesn't scale to an arbitrary number of strings be appended -- and `snprintf` may not be available everywhere.

Comment: It doesn't? What's the cutoff? Is there a FMTSTRING_MAX or VA_ARGS_MAX?

Comment: @Dave: What I meant is that you can't use it without knowing in advance how many strings you need to concatenate (for example if you're reading data from a file).

Comment: But, unlike `strcat()`, it returns the number of characters written, so in a loop, it would still be faster: you could keep track of the offset, and `snprintf(..."%s"...)` over and over.

Comment: `strncat() is a "safer" version of strcat() that lets you specify the size of the target array.` It should, but it doesn't. I don't know what moron invented this function, but the length parameter is actually the maximum length of the source, not the destination. At least according to the manpage on my system. So you need to call it like this: `strncat(dest, src, (dest_size - strlen(dest) - 1))`.

Comment: @AlastairG Thanks for the correction. I've updated my answer.